# After turndown by North America, did Jewish refugee ships try to secretly beach and live somewhere uninhabited?

Tags: holocaust

*Apology if my question looks childish. I want to give my students the best answer to their questions. I do not know how to answer this readily, so I asked you all.*

One student brought up [Weather Station Kurt (Wetter-Funkgerät Land-26)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_Station_Kurt)) ["So, Kurt just sat there year after year, lifeless and unspotted, until 1977 when something called the Torngat Archaeological Project arrived. Sponsored by the Smithsonian Institution and Bryn Mawr College, the project spent two years surveying and gathering data from the Labrador coast."](https://veteransbreakfastclub.org/weather-station-kurt-the-only-armed-german-operation-on-north-american-soil-in-wwii)

["Weather Station Kurt was lost to history until 1977 when archeologists stumbled upon what they thought was an old Canadian weather station.](https://weather.com/news/news/german-world-war-ii-weather-station-kurt-north-america-franz-selinger-20140718) [Apart from its mother ships ill fate, the station remained undiscovered long after the war was over. In 1977, a geomorphologist, Peter Johnson, was conducting research near Martin Bay, when he stumbled upon the Kurt weather station."](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/world-war-ii/weather-station-kurt.html?firefox=1)

[image]

##### Then another student asked — whether after North America rebuffed these refugee ships from Europe like [MS *St. Louis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_St._Louis), these ships stealthily tried to land in the boondocks, where these Jewish refugees can try to survive until Victory in Europe Day?

She reckoned that as nobody found Weather Station Kurt until 1977, these Jewish refugees can eke out life in these boonies until VE day May 8 1945. **But she was referring to any land uninhabited on the Labrador Sea,  Atlantic Ocean, and Carribean Sea —  like empty islands on the Canadian, American coasts, Carribean —  not just northern Labrador.** Survival on these [desert islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_island) and [uninhabitable regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_uninhabited_regions)  might have higher chances than Nazi-occupied Europe. Even if Indigenous People stumbled on these Jewish refugees, Indigenous People  might not rat the Jews to North American governments.

#### If these Jewish refugee ships did not attempt these uninhabited regions, why not?

Comment: There's a big difference between a unmanned weather station going unnoticed (and it was only designed to operate for 6 months), and establishing a community of hundreds that would need to go unnoticed for years in an inhospitable wilderness.

Comment: @SteveBird thanks. apology if my question looks childish.  I want to give my students the best answer to their questions. I do not know how to answer this readily, so I asked you all.

Comment: The answer to your final question is probably that the captains of these vessels didn't even consider the possibility. Unoccupied lands are usually unoccupied because they can't sustain human life (lacking food/fresh water/places to shelter). The ships wouldn't have had the equipment or provisions to set-up and sustain a colony of hundreds in such an environment.

Comment: Impossible. There is a ship's manifest and a passenger list. As soon as the ship docks anywhere both are checked. The captain will be arrested if he had dumped a bunch of passengers anywhere else but in a legitimate port.

Comment: Have you ever watched the reality show Alone? It follows professional survivalists trying to survive a few months in the Canadian wilderness, armed with only a few tools they were able to bring. They struggle. Untrained and unequipped families with children wouldn't stand a chance.

Comment: Interestingly, Wikipedia notes that the captain of the St Louis did consider beaching the ship - but to ensure that the passengers could not be sent back to Germany *on that ship* rather than to hide in the wilderness.

Comment: Additionally, the people who did setup the weather station went there planning to do that, and would have carried with themselves the supplies they thought would have been needed, and used ships prepared for that. The ships carrying refugees were not stocked for that, and beaching a ship on the coast can be very dangerous by itself.

Comment: As KillingTime explains, uninhabited places were effectively uninhabitable. It might be relevant to know that there were small communities of Jews that settled in various pockets of the Caribbean though: https://www.theguardian.com/education/2001/aug/11/socialsciences.highereducation

Comment: For comparison: The current (February 4) temperature in Kangiqsualujjuaq (an Inuit settlement a bit south of the "Station Kurt") is -15F (highest) and -31F (the lowest). What percentage of the refugees do you think would have died during their first winter there? (Given the limited vegetation that can be used for fuel, no way to grow crops, no fishing  equipment.) In contrast, the ship returned to Belgium and most passengers managed to escape to safety before the German occupation. About 30% perished in Holocaust. And the ship's captain did not know that the war will start in 2 months...

Comment: @BrianZ - I'd agree with this, with the complicating proviso that the area in question was neither "uninhabited" nor "uninhabitable", unless you don't consider the hunter-gatherer Inuit peoples to count. Their arctic hunting techniques were the only effective way for humans to live independently in that area (which is why they were the only ones doing it). A boatload of European refugees could not reasonably be expected to pick up those skills quickly enough to survive a winter alone there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not, that is impossible. Even back then. Every ship needs two items to sail:

- a manifest, that states all cargo
- a passenger list

Without all of the above a ship is not allowed to sail. Those documents are checked in every port, no matter what.

It goes a bit further. You can't embark or disembark where ever you want. Passengers *(and/or crew)* can only embark/disembark in ports with custom/immigration facilities. Nowhere else.

Supposing a captain dumps his passengers somewhere in the middle of nowhere? That happened during the Jewish Exodus to Palestine mandate, for example. Ships sailed to Palestine, beached, hoping their passengers could disappear before authorities appeared.

The ship will be impounded and the captain will be arrested and prosecuted. That means that the ship won't be going anywhere, until steep fines are paid. What the organizers of those trips did was find very old ships that could be ditched commanded by captains who could be bribed.

The situation in Palestine (before it became Israel) was a bit different from the situation in your question. British mandate authorities were at a loss what to do. Pre-war Canadian and American authorities were not.

In your example there wouldn't be any doubt. Supposing a captain brings his passengers ashore in a remote desolate area, he will be arrested in the next port of call, and his ship will be impounded. At least he can expect to be charged with illegal immigration. He probably would be charged with premeditated manslaughter or murder, the crew would be complicit.
When you bring a lot of people ashore in a remote area, people run the risk of dying there. They don't actually have to die, running the risk is enough to make the charges stick.

I used to work in a travel agency as cruise expert. What I described are international laws at sea: [SOLAS](https://www.imo.org/en/About/Conventions/Pages/International-Convention-for-the-Safety-of-Life-at-Sea-(SOLAS),-1974.aspx#:%7E:text=Under%20the%20regulation%2C%20ships%20should,or%20loss%20of%20watertight%20integrity.). The International Convention for the Safety of Life at Sea regulations are international, they apply to all maritime nations. Of course they didn't exist before 1974, but local laws and international treaties did exist and were internationally enforced.

Comment: "Supposing a captain dumps his passengers somewhere in the middle of nowhere? That happened during the Jewish Exodus to Palestine/Israel after WW2, for example." can you elaborate pls? where did this captain dump?

Comment: Ships were beached.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. From failing to distinguish between the real consequences of illegal activity (committing a crime) and of activities truly physically impossible; to being unaware of the difficulties of beaching a large ship and that virtually every place on the Labrador coast with a beach already had a (albeit sparsely) populated "*outport*"; to the bitter winter conditions on the Labrador coast [Cartwright daily highs in Feb., 2023, for a week, actual T not wind chill:](https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/nl-32_metric_e.html): -21C, -18C, -15C, -3C, -13C, -16C, -14C.

Comment: To improve: Describe the physical difficulties in actually beaching a modern vessel without shore assistance; in disembarking passengers from the beached vessel who might not be physically fit; and then in refloating the vessel. Discuss the relative rarity of "*beaches*", both sand and rock. Discuss the difficulties perhaps of the Plymouth Pilgrims their first winter, in a much friendlier environment than the Labrador coast, or even of the firsts Virginia colonies even further south.